# The Missing Dollar

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, lateral-thinking

3 men walk into a restaurant with 25 coins each and order food.

The bill is 72 coins.

The 3 men pay their 25 coins each to the waiter and ask him to return quickly with the 3 coins change.

The owner discounts this bill to 70 coins.

The waiter on his way back **keeps 2 coins**, and gives each of the men their 1 coin. So **each man has finally paid 24 coins each**.

So the total coins accounted for is -
2 kept by waiter + 24x3 paid by men = 74 coins

Where is the missing 1 coin?

Comment: This was actually posted sometime yesterday as well

Comment: @Inazuma and some time earlier in the week I believe...  Someone should add a "Please confirm that this is not the missing dollar riddle" checkbox to the question submission process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not 2 kept by waiter and 24x3 paid by men in the end. It's:

> 2 kept by waiter
>  3x1 left for men as change
>  70 went for the bill

Because

> You can't calculate the total adding "kept" to "paid" (+ to -)